# getting error while reading config file in django settings

Tags: python, django

I have this in my settings

```
import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('parameters.ini')

database_name = parser.get('database', 'myname')
```

i want to get the parameters from in file.

```
[database]
name = python_mydb
username = python
password = test
```

i get this error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
[Thu Jun 06 02:42:36 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.98]     raise NoSectionError(section)
[Thu Jun 06 02:42:36 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.98] NoSectionError: No section: 'database'
```

if i use same code in ipython then i dont get any error and i can see the `name`

Comment: I think there is some inconsistency in Your question. `parser.get('mysec', 'myname')` this part looks strange.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing  `database_name = parser.get('database', 'name')`?

Comment: sorry that was typo , i was checking with other name as well

Comment: what is the console output for `parser.read('parameters.ini')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ConfigParser.read](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read) *silently* ignore missing files.

My *guess* is `parameters.ini` is *not* on the right path while running your script from your Django application.